# How to read file from jetty server

Tags: java

My project is based on jetty server. ( java server and java script in the client )

I want to read javascript files and load them to the project.

I want to do it in dynamic way.

The problem that I don't want to read the files from c:.... but to use the jetty server to read those files.

I know the class of the project that I want to read the files but I dont know how to read the files.

If i will give the location of the folder C:..... then I will get the files but it is not the right way.

is it possible to read files in the project from the jetty server based on the name of the class of the project ?

How i can do it ?

Comment: Could you have another go at describing your problem?  What have you tried and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place those files within your web application's WAR file under a path on the class-path, this way they will be accessible as resources to your app using relative paths.

Comment: My suggestion was based on the assumption that those JS files are predefined. If they can increase or change by time, then they shouldn't be part of your WAR file. You should consider adding them to a path on the class-path outside of your WAR. I haven't used Jetty before, but perhaps there's a way to configure your app's class-path.

Comment: The files could be changed what did you mean by You should consider adding them to a path on the class-path outside of your WAR ?

Comment: Instead of bundling the JS files within your WAR file, and to avoid having to deal with updating the WAR file according to your first comment. You could for instance add the files to a folder and configure that folder on Jetty as part of your application's class-path. I'm not familiar with Jetty per se but this should be doable in theory at least. I have more experience with Application Servers such as IBM WebSphere which is in a different league.